# JavaFX plotting LinexChart

Tags: javafx

I am trying to learn how plot graph using JavaFX and there is my code where I trying to draw the very simple sin series:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

   final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
   final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

   @FXML
   private LineChart<Number, Number> ExactChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

   private Series sin_series = new Series();


   @FXML
   private void plotTheChart(ActionEvent event){
       int N = 100;
       double x0 = -Math.PI;
       double X = Math.PI;
       double h = (X-x0)/(N);
       double[] x = new double[N];
       double[] y = new double[N];

       x[0] = x0;
       for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
           x[i] = x[i-1] + h;
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
           y[i] = Math.sin(x[i]);
       }
       sin_series.setName("sin");

       for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
           sin_series.getData().add(new Data(x[i], y[i]));
       }
       ExactChart.getData().addAll(sin_series);
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

   }
}
```

But when I execute it I face following problem:

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Double and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')**

I do not see any part of the code where I am castin double to string. Can you show me where I am wrong?

Comment: I notice you have two `NumberAxis` defined: `xAxis` and `yAxis`. You use these to create your `LineChart`. But you're using FXML which means your `LineChart` is replaced by the one defined in the FXML file. Look at your FXML file to see what axes you've configured. If one of them is a `CategoryAxis` then replace it with a `NumberAxis`. Also remove the `xAxis` and `yAxis` fields and stop initializing the `ExactChart` field. Then make sure you don't use raw types. You should have `Series<Number, Number> sin_series = new Series<>()` and `new Data<>(x[i], y[i])`.

Comment: Also, according to Java naming conventions field names start with a lower case letter and follow the "camel case" pattern (i.e. `ExactChart` → `exactChart`, `sin_series` → `sinSeries`). Following naming conventions helps others, and possibly you, read your code. It also helps Stack Overflow apply the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thank you  worked! Aslo thanks for remark.